# Excel countif doesn't work with numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

in the following example you get output '0' for a strange reason. Can someone explain why this occurs and what I can do about it? (The format of the cells is "text")

```
rows A:A
---------
1
11
111
22
2
1111

formula:
--------
=COUNTIF(A$1:A$65536;"1*")

result: 
-------
0

wanted result:
--------------
4
```

Comment: The test condition in Excel's `COUNTIF` is not a regular expression, or similar.  It takes the form of "[conditional operator][value]". Alphabetical [value]'s (for English, at least) are tested by default in case-insensitive alphabetical order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your values are numbers. Test by using

`=ISNUMBER(A1)`

If you apply text format **after** entry it doesn't change the format to text - you either have to apply text format **before** entry or enter the values with a preceding apostrophe (to indicate text) like

`'111`

`COUNTIF` function with wildcards doesn't work with numbers. You can use this formula to get the required result (which will work with text, numbers or a mix)

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(1;A$1:A$65536))+0)`